# Click image to initiate a search in Rails

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have placed an image of a magnifying glass within a text box so that the user can click this to initiate their search. At the moment if you press 'Enter' the search function is carried out, but need a click event also.

This is my HTML and CSS as it is:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/blog" class="searchPosts" method="get">
  <input id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search Here" type="text" />      
</form>


.searchPosts {
  background:url("/assets/bg_dots_grey.png") repeat;
}

#search {
 background:url('/assets/search.png') no-repeat right;
 padding-right:0px;
}
```

The Ruby to produce the form:

```
<%= form_tag blog_path, :method => 'get', :class => 'searchPosts'  do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :placeholder => 'Search Here' %>
<% end %>
```

Notice there is no submit_tag as I did not want the user to click a button to carry out the request.

Do I need to add the submit_tag back in and style that with CSS to fit within the input field? Or is this a case for a jQuery solution? If not how would I go about this?

Comment: I think you will have to submit the form on the click event, sounds better than the CSS way you already have in mind.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a button after the search box and if possible styling it in such a way that it looks as if it is part of the search box. Then have the search.png within the button. Much better than using unnecessary JS to submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, **all you have in your form is an image inside the text box** via css's background property. This **will not** accept a *click event*. Create a submit button and style it with your "magnifying glass" properties instead of the standard button properties.

Placing the button inside the text field is just a matter of relative positioning in css. Do a *search for more details on that.*

Having `<button type="submit" class="magGlass"></button>` will allow it to be clicked and **fire the submit event**.